# How to install xvidcap on Jetson Nano Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, make

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.joeldare.com/wiki/linux:installing_xvidcap_under_ubuntu) to install `xvidcap` on Jetson Nano, so I do:

```sh
./configure
```

Then I get this error:

```sh
configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one
```

Can you please tell me how can I install `xvidcap` on Jetson Nano correctly? thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Nano OR Ubuntu, Nano is not Ubuntu.

Comment: @David Jetson Nano is a board: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/autonomous-machines/embedded-systems/jetson-nano/

Comment: @Bilal Were there error in the configure phase? If so please [edit] the question and post the full error messages.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks for your kind suggestion, I have updated the error message.

Comment: It is also a version of a Ubuntu like OS.

Comment: Apparently the software doesn't support ARM.